# TFLite model maker custom object detector training using tfrecord

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to train a custom object detector using tflite model maker (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection). I want to deploy trained tflite model to coral edgeTPU. I want to use tensorflow tfrecord (multiple) as input for training a model like object detection API. I tried with
**tflite_model_maker.object_detector.DataLoader(
tfrecord_file_patten, size, label_map, annotations_json_file=None
)** but I am not able to work around it. I have following questions.

- Is it possible to tfrecord for training like mentioned above?
- Is it also possible to pass multiple CSV files for training?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple CSV files, you could probably just append one file to the other. Then you'd just have to pass one csv file.

As for passing a tfrecord instead, this should be possible. I'm also attempting to do this, so if I get it working I'll update my post. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader.py#L102-L367), it seems `from_cache` is the function internally used. Following that structure, should be able to create a DataLoader object similarly:

```
train_data = DataLoader(tfrecord_file_patten, meta_data['size'],
                      meta_data['label_map'], ann_json_file)
```

In this case, tfrecord_file_patten should be a tfrecord of your training data. You can construct the validation and test data the same way. This will work provided you're constructing your TFRecords correctly. There appears to be some inconsistency to how it's done in different places, so make sure you follow the same structure in creating the TFRecords as [found in the ModelMaker source](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/e0644ca55e6d14a78e61fd189934a238048a31cf/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/third_party/efficientdet/dataset/create_pascal_tfrecord.py#L135). This worked for me. One specific thing to watch out for is to use an integer for the 'image/source_id' feature in your TFExamples. If you use a string it'll throw an error.